# Find probability of doctor's visit during a week, if he visits 3 of his 40 patients every day

Tags: probability

A country doctor has 40 patients.  Every day he visits 3 of them.  Jason is one of the doctor's patients.  What is the probability that Jason will be visited by the doctor in any particular week?

Jason is married.  What is the probability that he or his wife will be visited by the doctor in any particular week?

Comment: "Every day he visits 3 of them."  Do you mean he visits three *different* patients every day?

Comment: It probably has something to do with how sick Jason is.

Comment: Is Jason's wife also a patient of the doctor?

Comment: Does the doctor ever visit people who aren't his patients? Are he and Jason's wife having ... oh, never mind.

Comment: Can we assume that the doctor visits the patients on each day of the week (including weekends)?  Can he visit the same patient twice in one week?

Comment: No, just weekdays.  And no, we assume that he's not visiting the same patient each week.

Comment: It is unreasonable to assume that visits to Jason and partner are *independent*. But if we do assume that, the probability they are both visited is $(15/40)(14/39)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**:  My original answer is shown below the line.  Andre Nicolas has explained in the comments why it is incorrect.  The correct answer to the first question is $\frac{15}{40}$ as can be seen if we imagine picking 15 balls out of 40 balls in an urn.

---

We assume that each patient is equally likely to be chosen to be visited by the doctor for a given week.  (The answer would be different if this wasn't the case.)  You mention that the doctor only visits on weekdays and that he doesn't visit the same patient more than once in a week.  He is thus choosing 15 patients from the 40, where each patient is equally likely to be chosen.

Let's label the patients $P_1$, $P_2$, ..., $P_{14}$, $P_{15}$ and let's say the patients are chosen one at a time.

The probability that Jason is chosen as $P_1$ is $\frac{1}{40}$.  (He is one of the 40 people equally likely to be chosen to be $P_1$.)

If Jason was not chosen as $P_1$, then the probability that Jason is chosen as $P_2$ is $\frac{1}{39}$.  (He is one of the 39 remaining people equally likely to be chosen to be $P_2$.)

If Jason was not chosen as $P_1$ or as $P_2$, then the probability that Jason is chosen as $P_3$ is $\frac{1}{38}$, and so on.

The probability that Jason is $P_1$ or $P_2$ or ... or $P_{14}$ or $P_{15}$ is $\frac{1}{40}+\frac{1}{39}+\ldots+\frac{1}{27}+\frac{1}{26}$.  The probability of the union of these events is the sum of their probabilities because these events are disjoint (they cannot happen at the same time).

Comment: As for the wife, is the wife one of the 40 patients of the doctor? Also, is it possible for the doctor to visit Jason and his wife as patients during the same week?

Comment: The probability is $\frac{15}{40}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, are you saying the answer to the first question is $\frac{15}{40}$?  But this is only true if the patients can be visited more than once in a week.  The OP has mentioned in comments that patients are not visited more than once in a week.

Comment: Yes, I am saying that. If you want to use a sequential argument, which is more complicated than necessary, probability Jason is second is probability he is not first (prob. $39/40$) times the probability he is chosen second *given* he was not chosen first ($1/39$).

Comment: If I recall, your first answer was right. It is just a question of rolling back.

Comment: I'm leaving my answer as is, so that future readers can see my error and learn from it.  Thank you very much for your comments.